# How do I modify button characteristics in a jqgrid form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I managed to get the button (name: "SelectStores") to display but it is in a default mode and does not match the rest of the form in color and shape.  How to I change these properties?

Thank you.

```
colModel:[{name: "PCROWID", width: 60, align: "center", editable:true, hidden:true, editoptions: {readonly:true}},
            {name: "PCST", width: 60, align: "center", editable:true, editoptions: {readonly:true}, editrules: {required:true, number:false}},
            {name: "PCLSEQ", width: 60, align: "center", editable:true, editoptions: {readonly:true}, editrules: {required:true, number:true}, formatter:'number', formatoptions:{decimalPlaces: 0, defaultValue: '0'}},
            {name: "PCACTIVE", width: 60, align: "center", editable:true, editrules: {edithidden:true}, edittype:"checkbox", editoptions: {value:"Y:N"}},
            {name: "SelectStores", width: 80, align: "center", editable:true, hidden:true, editrules: {edithidden:true}, edittype:"button", editoptions: {value:"Select Stores"}},
```

Answer (score 0):

This data set is an array of objects. So you can access each object by its index in the array, starting with 0 for the first object.

So:

```
colModel[0] = {
            name: "PCROWID",
            width: 60,
            align: "center",
            editable: true,
            hidden: true,
            editoptions: {
                readonly: true
            }
```

So, the object you are trying to access is in the 4th index, and can be accessed at:

```
colModel[4]
```

From there, each individual property can be accessed using dot notation:

```
    colModel[4].name   // this would return "Select Store"
    colModel[4].align     // this would return "center"
    colModel[4].editrules.edithidden // returns true
```

So you can also assign new values in this same way:

```
colModel[4].align = "left" 
colmodel[4].width = 60
```

Keep in mind, that this only works if your array of objects stays in the same order. If you add a new item to the beginning of your array, the item you are trying to access will no longer be at index of 4, and suddenly you will be editing the wrong item.

So if they are all uniform and should have the same properties, you may want to consider doing something like a loop, to either normalize ALL properties of all objects, or to find the one you are looking for:

```
for( var i = 0, length = colModel.length; i < length; i++ ){
    // set all widths to 60
    colModel[i].width = 60;

    // set only the "SelectStores" button alignment to "left"
    if(colModel[i].name === "SelectStores"){
        colModel[i].align = "left"; 
    } 
}
```

Depending on your exact purposes, there are likely more efficient ways to do this, but this would get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  This helps me a great deal with understanding the jqgrid construct.  I do have a follow up question.  Where does the code samples: ("colModel[4].align = "left" ") you provided go in the overall format?

Answer (score 0):

I do need to clarify my question.  The button I was trying to modify was in the edit form not in the grid itself.  That column is hidden in the grid.

I did find a solution and that is in the edit section of my code where I can work with the edit form directly.

Here is my solution:

```
$('#SelectStores').click(function() { 
   ShowExtendedData(); 
 }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all");
```